# spring aop JoinPoint getArgs() return null

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Aspect works well, but why the method joinPoint.getArgs () returns a null?
What is the reason? How to fix it? 
Standalone version works correctly, but when using Jetty always returns null. I use Spring 3.2, Spring Security.

```
In config Spring: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

@Validated
public interface Service {

    public String update(Long userId, String name);

}


@Service("myService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @MyAnnotation
    @Override    
    public String update(Long userId, String name) {

     //...
    }

}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {                   

    @Around("@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object myAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation annotation)                                    throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();            
        args = null!
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your context. This works for me.

Comment: I spent all day)
Object [] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
log.info ("Args {}", args);
Show only first argument, which was null. Closed!

Comment: It happens to all of us!

Comment: @rdm what am I missing here? I'm getting 6 null objects in an array...